# Shouldn't [random] be renamed to [randomness]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [random](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) evokes the idea of a "random" post, something which is categorically disallowed on Stack Exchange.

Comment: "The tag random evokes the idea of a [tag:random] post" [citation needed]

Answer (score 8):

> The tag [random](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) evokes the idea of a "random" post

I don't see it. As in, I don't see a problem. Before you started about it, I never thought people would see [random](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) as an indication of a random post. Random posts are not allowed on the SE network.

On top of that, there's the tag usage help. When you hover over the tag, it shows the following:

> This tag is for questions pertaining to random numbers, whether pseudo random or truly random.

TL;DR:
No.